# How to dynamically render plotly plots in a loop within a PDF RMarkdown document?

Tags: r, loops, pdf, plotly, r-markdown

I am trying to create a series of plotly plots within an RMarkdown pdf document and then render them dynamically in a loop. However, I am encountering an issue where the plots are not being displayed when I use a loop. When I index each plot individually in separate code chunks, the plots render as expected. However, when I try to render the plots using a loop, no plots are displayed.

Here is a minimal working example:

````
    ---
    title: "Test loop plot"
    output: pdf_document
    ---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

    library(plotly)
    library(datasets)
    ```

    ```{r prepare plots}
    plot1 <- plot_ly(data = mtcars, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
    plot2 <- plot_ly(data = mtcars, x = ~hp, y = ~mpg, type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
    plot3 <- plot_ly(data = mtcars, x = ~qsec, y = ~mpg, type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
    # there are many more plots here in my application

    plot_list <- list(plot1, plot2, plot3)
    ```

    ```{r distinct indexing}
    # this works and produces the output as expected
    plot_list[[1]] 
    plot_list[[2]] 
    plot_list[[3]]
    ```

    ```{r dynamic indexing}
    # this does not work and produces no output
    for (plot in plot_list) {
      plot
    }
    ```
````

How can I fix this issue and dynamically render the plots within the loop? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

I tried to follow [this](https://plotly.com/r/embedding-graphs-in-rmarkdown/) guide, but it only seems to be apply for HTML output.

I already tried installing the webshot package as explained [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-widgets.html), but I did not get an output either.

Printing with print() the plots rather than calling them did not work at all for me.

Comment: [This should help.](https://plotly.com/r/embedding-graphs-in-rmarkdown/)

Comment: Thanks @Kat. This is a great resource I have found before (I am actually linking to it in my question). What they suggest only seems to work for HTML output though, not for PDF. Let me know if I overlooked anything.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this error a long time ago. Please try substituting the `for` loop with `lapply(plot_list, print)`.